# select with different parameter

Tags: php

hello this is the first time me ask on stackoverflow. so if i do wrong please forgive me. so here is my problem .

i wanna select staff that have the same schedule with other staff by where parameter is id_staff.

Here is my db:

[image: db]

I need the output is like this:

[image: desired]

but the parameter where is not schedule_id but id_staff
can i do that?
please help.
thank you.

Comment: Please post the query as plain text so we can copy it.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why can't you just change `team_op.id_schedule = 2001` to `team_op.id_staff = 105`?

Comment: Why is there an `id_staff` column in the `schedule` table? This is a many-to-many relationship, and that's in the `team_op` table.

Comment: @Barmar I think the OP wants to select all the staff that has the same `id_schedule` as `team_op.id_staff = 105`'s schedule. Would the `INNER JOIN`, in its current format do that, by just changing to `WHERE team_op.id_staff = 105`?

Comment: @Sean Yes, I think it would.

Comment: @Sean yeah that what i want to do. how can i do that?
sorry @Sean i don`t understand what u ask?